# Tabs for mobile application

Tags: mobile, navigation

I am developing a mobile application that has a persistent nav bar at the top with no tabs or footer at the bottom. However there is one screen of this app where I would like to use tabs.

Would it be better to try to put the tabs for this page as a sub-header at the top, or can I conditionally show a footer like [this example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/)?

I'm mostly asking which is more common practice or user-friendly, as I realize both are acceptable options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a huge answer, deleted it and got to the point: sub-header

Mixing navigation styles isn't a good idea, you will likely confuse your users.

The key to good navigation is a clear structure and consistent behaviour, so if you can try to make it as simple and easy for your users then you'll find that they will appreciate it more. Same thing with answers too!