# When to use which navigation in android

Tags: navigation, android

I'm planning my app design with material design and they offer good description on navigation:[They describe](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#lateral-navigation)  which option with how much content to use.

In general: my choices are either the Navigation drawer or the Bottom navigation bar (I'd use tabs as described in the link as a lower hierarchy selector). 
But both have different characteristics and appearance in my eyes: With the drawer you can categorize the different areas much more visible, on the other hand with the bottom nav bar you can switch faster.

Furthermore it is not described which one to use in which case for best practices.

About my app: It surely has 3 top main sections (if not more, I'm not yet sure if I should subdivide the learning section): 'Products', 'Learning Section' , 'Analytics'.
The 'learning section has children like: 'lessons', 'tasks', 'questions'. BUT: I think the nav drawer might take the user too much out of context so I am thinking about cutting the different categories so they fit all into an bottom bar nav.

My users are mostly adult digital natives, with a passion for business stuff
How can I choose which one suits my app best?

Comment: Are you only supporting mobile devices and not tablet or desktop? How many top-level destinations do you have? Would it be worth reducing your available screen space to always show navigation at the bottom?

Comment: Can you add some specifics here, as it is difficult to answer with no context on what type of app it is, who users are, etc.

Comment: You can check this question: [link](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102439/android-ux-when-to-use-bottom-navigation-and-when-to-use-tabs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

I was debating the same thing. My decision came down to two things:

1. How many destinations I plan to have
2. How often will people switch between destinations

Check out their description of the Botton navigation bar (https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage) and Navigation drawer (https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#usage).

What kind of app are you designing?